# Can't delete mongodb document using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm trying to delete one specific document using (_id) with pymongo and i can't do it, some idea..

thks.

I have this code:

```py
s = "ISODate('{0}')".format(nom_fitxer_clean)
#i generate the next string.. (ISODate('2018-11-07 00:00:00'))

myquery = { "_id": s }
#query string ({'_id': "ISODate('2018-10-07 00:00:00')"})
mycol.delete_one(myquery)
```

I do not get any errors or delete the document.

UPDATE:
Document
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one possible solution could be to replace ISODate with ObjectId in your query string.

Moreover, `delete_one` deletes the first object which matches with your query. So it is possible that there exist multiple objects which match your query?

Comment: ({'_id': "ObjectId ('2018-10-07 00:00:00')"}) like this.. ?

Comment: I would try this, because the "_id" usually stores an object of type ObjectId.

Could you post an example entry of your database?

Comment: I've tried it at my local mongo and I guess you have forgotten the milliseconds with the Z at the end of your pymongo query string :-) 

This is my command:
`db.getCollection('test').deleteOne({"_id": ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")})`